# Should I rollback edit?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289995/how-to-get-help-in-r/15290370#15290370) on Stack Overflow where I am also author of accepted answer. Author of last revision basically changed both question and answer. Now, the question is slightly different and answer is almost completely rewritten.

I have to admit that edit is of high quality, but 1) I feel that my answer was more dense - easier to read and use, 2) I really do not like the fact that both question and answer were edited.

Should I rollback?

Edit: I decided that I won't rollback the edit.

Comment: I guess your talking about [this self answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15289995/692942) in which case I'd say no don't roll back.

Comment: In a different question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724602/in-css-why-am-i-unable-to-place-background-colored-box-using-div/27724821) the question was edited in such a way as to fix the problem.  The (correct) answers now do not make sense in light of the (edited) question.  Guidance?  Or should I ask a new `meta` question?

Comment: @BobBrown If the edit to the question fixed the problem, roll it back. (If you have the rep.) Fixes to code that invalidate the problem are bad for questions, as they make the OP look like they are just trolling or not putting in everything they need.

Comment: @Kendra: I have not enough rep to roll back edits.  Perhaps someone who can will see this.

Comment: How does one comment a rolled-back answer? There seems to be no way to explain to the editor why we rolled back.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's entirely your decision.

There's nothing inherently wrong with that kind of edit.

If you genuinely don't feel it's an improvement and prefer the original then feel free to roll it back however.

Answer (score 21):

My apologies.  I started trying to add a little more structure to the answer and it developed into a bigger change.  Creating a new answer would have resulted in 90% duplication of content, which I didn't think would have helped readers.

If you are really unhappy with the update then I won't be offended if you want to rollback – I'll repost as a separate answer.  That said, having just one good answer is better for readers (less reading), so the ideal outcome might be that you edit the existing answer to form a hybrid, with the best of both our answers.

Comment: I think people can be too protective of what is after all community owned content and anything that enhances that I don't see a problem with.

Answer (score 14):

[The edit on the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15290370/4) should be rolled back. The person that made the edit should just have posted a new answer instead.

Completely changing a highly upvoted, accepted answer like that, especially on a question that's over a year old, is really not the way to add to this site.

The edit on the question seems okay, although it does change the intent of the question a little bit. I wouldn't roll that one back.

Comment: Changing older answers (even upvoted ones) *is* part of the site's model. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing "Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."